# AWS Autoscalling Rolling over Connections to new Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Is it possible to automatically 'roll over' a connection between auto scaled instances?

Given instances which provide a compute intensive service, we would like to

1. Autoscale a new instance after CPU reachs say 90%
2. Have requests for service handled by the new instance.

It does not appear that there is a way with the AWS Dashboard to set this up, or have I missed something?

Comment: What type of connection does your instance accept?  http/https? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [load balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html). If you're using HTTP, this works pretty much out of the box. Clients open connections to the load balancer, which then distributes individual HTTP requests from the connection evenly across instances in your auto scaling group. When a new instance joins the group, the load balancer automatically shifts a portion of the incoming requests over to the new instance.

Things get a bit trickier if you're speaking a protocol other than HTTP(S). A generic TCP load balancer can't tell where one "request" ends and the next begins (or if that even makes sense for your protocol), so incoming TCP connections get mapped directly to a particular backend host. The load balancer will route new connections to the new instance when it spins up, but it can't migrate existing connections over.

Typically what you'll want to do in this scenario is to have clients periodically close their connections to the service and create new ones - especially if they're seeing increased latencies or other evidence that the instance they're talking to is overworked.